# ssh not working from one server to anther

Tags: ssh

I have 2 servers server A and server B. I am able to ssh to both the servers from my local laptop and from a third server say server C But I am unable to ssh into server B from server A and vice versa. I am getting error 
`ssh: connect to host serverA port 22: No route to host`. Also, ping is not working from within the 2 servers on each other. But ping works from my local and from a third server `server c`.I am unable to figure out the exact cause. Please help me

Comment: Does `traceroute` work between those two servers?

Comment: What's the network setup like? How are all these computers interconnected? Are there any firewalls (either hardware or software) involved, and if so how are they configured?